How to build a docker image based on python anaconda project
I'm not a python expert this my first app which I deploy using python, I hope you help to build a docker image of my project.
I have a project based on anaconda with python version 3.12.7 the app works as expected locally, now what i'm trying to do is to build a docker image. the first this I did I executed conda list -e > requirements.txt to create requirements.txt then I created an environment.yaml here's the content :
name: app

channels:
  - conda-forge
  - anaconda
dependencies:
  - pip:
      - -r file:requirements.txt

here's a part of requirements.txt :
psycopg2=2.9.9=py312h2bbff1b_0
pyarrow=16.1.0=py312h0158946_0
pydeck=0.8.0=py312haa95532_2
pygments=2.15.1=py312haa95532_1
pyparsing=3.2.0=py312haa95532_0
pyqt=5.15.10=py312hd77b12b_0
pyqt5-sip=12.13.0=py312h2bbff1b_0
pysocks=1.7.1=py312haa95532_0
python=3.12.7=h14ffc60_0
python-dateutil=2.9.0post0=py312haa95532_2
python-dotenv=0.21.0=py312haa95532_0
python-tzdata=2023.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pytz=2024.1=py312haa95532_0
pyyaml=6.0.2=py312h827c3e9_0
qt-main=5.15.2=h19c9488_10
re2=2022.04.01=hd77b12b_0
referencing=0.30.2=py312haa95532_0

and finnaly here's the Dockerfile
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
# setting the working directory 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN conda update --name base conda &&\
    conda env create --file environment.yaml
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "app", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
EXPOSE 8050
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit","run","main.py","--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]

when I run docker compose build --no-cache I got this error :
> [app 4/4] RUN conda update --name base conda &&    conda env create --file environment.yaml:
1.202 Channels:
1.202  - defaults
1.202 Platform: linux-64
1.202 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
3.334 Solving environment: ...working... done
3.455
3.455 ## Package Plan ##
3.455
3.455   environment location: /opt/conda
3.455
3.455   added / updated specs:
3.455     - conda
3.455
3.455
3.455 The following packages will be downloaded:
3.455
3.455     package                    |            build
3.455     ---------------------------|-----------------
3.455     ca-certificates-2024.11.26 |       h06a4308_0         131 KB
3.455     conda-24.11.1              |  py312h06a4308_0         1.2 MB
3.455     ------------------------------------------------------------
3.455                                            Total:         1.3 MB
3.455
3.455 The following packages will be UPDATED:
3.455
3.455   ca-certificates                      2024.9.24-h06a4308_0 --> 2024.11.26-h06a4308_0
3.455   conda                              24.9.2-py312h06a4308_0 --> 24.11.1-py312h06a4308_0
3.455
3.455
3.455 Proceed ([y]/n)?
3.712
3.712 Downloading and Extracting Packages: ...working... done
3.712 Preparing transaction: ...working... done
3.721 Verifying transaction: ...working... done
3.746 Executing transaction: ...working... done
5.156 Warning: you have pip-installed dependencies in your environment file, but you do not list pip itself as one of your conda dependencies.  Conda may not use the correct pip to install your packages, and they may end up in the wrong place.  Please add an explicit pip dependency.  I'm adding one for you, but still nagging you.
5.298 Channels:
5.298  - conda-forge
5.298  - anaconda
5.298  - defaults
5.298 Platform: linux-64
5.298 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
18.35 Solving environment: ...working... done
19.88
 done                                                ...
23.73 Preparing transaction: done
23.83 Verifying transaction: done
24.60 Executing transaction: done
26.13 Installing pip dependencies: - Pip subprocess error:
27.22 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: No connection adapters were found for 'file:requirements.txt'
27.22
27.22
27.23 Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
27.23 ['/opt/conda/envs/app/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/usr/src/app/condaenv.i6m9rpht.requirements.txt', '--exists-action=b']
27.23 Pip subprocess output:
27.23
27.2failed
27.23
27.23 CondaEnvException: Pip failed
27.23
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c conda update --name base conda &&    conda env create --file environment.yaml" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Could anyone help please ?

Try removing "file:" in the yaml file. I don't think that this syntax works for the recent versions of pip.
